# PHP - Best way to find URL root from string?

Tags: php, regex, url, xpath

I use PHP.

**I have an URL that looks like this**

http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/mydir2/?something=hello

**I want this:**

http://www.mydomain.com

**I did it like this but it feels like the wrong way to do it**

To long and ugly.

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/mydir2/?something=hello';
$root_url_a = explode('/', $url);
$root_url = $root_url_a[0] . '//' .  $root_url_a[2];
$root_url_clean = $root_url_a[2];
```

**Suggestions**

- Regex?
- Xpath?
- Some for me unknown PHP function?

The shortest most correct way of doing it will get my vote.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: `XPath`? Since when was a url a xml doc?

Comment: Someone downvoted the entire thread – I'm upvoting your question, it is not an invalid one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/mydir2/?something=hello";
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

// Would echo:
http://www.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? This is a perfectly legitimate way of parsing the url? If anything is wrong with this code – please advice.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter but this wouldn't do what you claim as the PHP_URL_HOST portion does not include the scheme so all you would get would be `www.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 3):

Ok here is an example:

```
$url = parse_url('http://www.mydomain.com/mydir/mydir2/?something=hello');

echo $url->scheme.'://'.$url->host;
```

Is along the right lines.

Though technically this is not even right since depending on whether you send in a scheme or not for a url `parse_url` can actually change the way it assigns variables, so I wrote:

```
function return_url($url){
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);

    if(!$parsed_url){
        return false;
    }

    if(isset($parsed_url['scheme'])){
        if(!isset($parsed_url['host'])){
            return false;
        }else{
            return $parsed_url['scheme'].'://'.$parsed_url['host'];
        }
    }

    if(isset($parsed_url['path'])){
        return 'http://'.$parsed_url['path'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I would say RTM ;)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
?>
```

Comment: Please – consider to test your code, or make sure you read the question correct before posting an answer. Not copy pasting directly from PHP.net. He is not looking for the path, but the host of the url.

Comment: You could have added a comment for that, to add an answer to the question that tells them to read the manual and then post misleading code that you obviously didn't test doesn't help anyone.

Comment: This still won't return what he is looking for

Comment: I think he can figure that out himself.